# payroll program, need help simply a patterned event, new to python

Tags: python

so i'm learning python and decided to program a payroll for my company as practice.
for the usa bi-weekly  tax, there is pattern to the amount you need to pay, here is a short code for example

> ```
>     if n >= 760 and n < 780:
>        gt = 45
>     if n >= 780 and n < 800:
>        gt = 47
>     if n >= 800 and n < 820:
>        gt = 49
>     if n >= 820 and n < 840:
>        gt = 51
> ```

here n is the salary, and gt is the tax to be paid.

as you can see, the range of n is a constant 20, and tax increase by a constant 2

this is true from 720 - 1000, starting from 1000 however, the rate of the tax increases by constant 3

i want to to be able  to include a salary range from 720 to 2000, is there a way to do this, or do i have to do it the hard way and write them all out?

Comment: If n = 20, won't it always be less than all those numbers? I see you're checking to see if it is or not. I think you might be doing this wrong, or else I'm misunderstanding something

Comment: You mentioned you're learning python; I suggest checking out [project euler](http://projecteuler.net/). It's got a bunch of programming problems on there that I find helpful when learning a new language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd branch on your two ranges and then use some math to get the tax amount:

```
if n >= 720 and n < 1000:
    gt = 2*(( n - 720 ) / 20) + 41
elif n >= 1000 and n < 2000:
    gt = 3*(( n - 1000 ) / 20) + 67
```

Comment: thanks you! how did you figure the math out? btw, how do i mark this solved?

Comment: To mark it solved click the empty tick mark next to the answer - it should go green. The math I did with some trial and error, but mainly you subtract the starting value from n (720 or 1000) to give 0 at the start of the range, divide by 20 to get 0,1,2,3 etc representing each block of 20, multiply by the step value (2 or 3) to get a sequence of 0,2,4,6 etc and 0,3,6,9 then add on the value at which each range starts.